# Oracle return the value of a variable

Tags: oracle

I am migrating Microsoft Sql Server Database to Oracle 19c, a query migrated is failing:

```
            DECLARE cardnum varchar2(100);
            BEGIN
            MyProcedure('ES', cardnum );
            SELECT cardnum;
            END;
```

The error returned is:

```
     PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

I think that the error is in the line 4:

```
     SELECT cardnum;
```

The procedure sets the value of the variable, therefore I need to return the value of the variable "cardnum".

What should i use instead of select clausule?

Note --> this query is used from net core with Dapper.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you already have `cardnum`, procedure set it as its `OUT` parameter, you don't have to do anything about it.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure myprocedure(par_1 in varchar2, par_2 out varchar2) is
  2  begin
  3    par_2 := 'ABC';
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.

SQL> declare
  2    cardnum varchar2(100);
  3  begin
  4    myprocedure('ES', cardnum);
  5
  6    dbms_output.put_line('Cardnum = ' || cardnum);
  7  end;
  8  /
Cardnum = ABC

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

If you want to select it, you can - but PL/SQL requires an `INTO` clause. For example:

```
SQL> declare
  2    cardnum varchar2(100);
  3    l_var   varchar2(100);
  4  begin
  5    myprocedure('ES', cardnum);
  6
  7    select cardnum into l_var from dual;
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

It depends on what you actually want to do with `cardnum` ...